# When is this not an equivalence relation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, equivalence-relations

I'm given this relation on a group $G$ and a positive integer $n$.

$$a \sim b \Longleftrightarrow ab^{-1} = g^n$$

for some element $g \in G$. Clearly this relation is symmetric ($aa^{-1} = e^n$) and reflexive, so if it's not going to be an equivalence relation it will fail to be transitive, but if $G$ is commutative it will be transitive ($g^nh^n = (gh)^n$). So I'm looking for an example in a non-abelian group of an $a,b,c$ so that $a \sim b, b \sim c$, but $a$ is not related to $c$.

I've tried hard to find one in $S_3$ and $S_4$ with no luck. Any hints?

Comment: Indeed, thanks for clarifying, @BrianM.Scott!  I was interpreting that g and n were fixed, and hence my comment.

Comment: Try $S_3$ with $n=3$. Using the operation table [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group_of_order_6#Summary_of_group_operations), I believe that $d\sim a\sim f$, but $d\not\sim f$.

Comment: @amWhy: If I’m reading it correctly, $n$ is fixed, but not $g$.

Comment: Well that interpretation certainly makes more sense! ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an equivalence relation if and only if the set $\{ g^n : g \in G \}$ of $n^{th}$ powers is a subgroup. Since it's normal (invariant under conjugation), it's a union of conjugacy classes, and for nice $G$ we can hope to determine exactly which conjugacy classes these are. Then if the sum of their orders doesn't divide $|G|$ they can't be a subgroup.

As Brian M. Scott says in the comments, if $G = S_3, n = 3$ then we are looking at the set of all third powers in $S_3$. A $3$-cycle satisfies $g^3 = e$ and a $2$-cycle is fixed by taking the third power, so the set of all third powers is exactly the set $\{ e, (12), (23), (31) \}$ of $2$-cycles, together with the identity. This has order $4$ and so can't be a subgroup: explicitly, $(12)(23) = (123)$ is not a $2$-cycle.